# angular quickstart app crashed on heroku

Tags: angular, heroku

I have downloaded anuglar2 quickstart from here:
https://github.com/angular/quickstart

It is working on localhost but when I pushed on Heroku it gives me the error:
`Application error`

What is going wrong with angular2 quickstart on Heroku?

Here is log detail from heorku admin:

```
2017-05-14T15:13:16.400648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-14T15:13:16.400445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
2017-05-14T15:13:16.400839+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
2017-05-14T15:13:16.401036+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-14T15:13:16.406429+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-14T15:13:16.406738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-14T15:13:16.406911+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-14T15:13:16.501756+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-14T15:13:16.486330+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: This question is still open for new answers as I'm unable to run angular quick start app on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

In  systemjs.config as

```
paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
```

Comment: Hi thanks, still getting the error, What about other portions of systemjs.config? like 
`map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',
...
`

Comment: npm version is: `3.10.10` I have checked on heroku app console, is it okay?